# leave equation number normal size for large equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I want to increase font size in math. formula in latex document, but leave the equation number normalsize.

Answer (score 4):

You can load `mathtools` and add to your preamble

```
\renewtagform{default}{\normalsize(}{)}
\usetagform{default}
```

Example:

```
 \begin{equation}
   a = b + c
 \end{equation}

\LARGE
 
 \begin{equation}
   a = b + c
 \end{equation}
```

[image]